# Perform one Mongoid query instead of two seperate Mongoid queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to perform the following two mongoid queries with just one mongoid query. I tried looking for the solution in Mongoid Documentation but couldn't find any.

Query 1

```
Event.where(:start_time.gte => current_date.to_s, :start_time.lte => date_after_2_weeks.to_s)
```

Query 2

```
Event.where(:stop_time.gte => current_date.to_s, :stop_time.lte => date_after_2_weeks.to_s)
```

Is there a way to execute the above two separate queries with just one? Please, help. I would appreciate it very much.

Thanks,
-Parash-

Comment: It might help if you explained what the point of the two queries was. Do you want the combined or "union" of both result sets? Or are you after the common or "intersection" of results?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Neil. I want the union of both result sets.

Comment: Then "No can do Doctor Jones". A union of two result sets is only achived by **two** queries (preferably in parallel where your language and libraries support this). MongoDB does not do SQL type "union" queries or any other form of "join"

Comment: Thanks Neil. Didn't know that. I appreciate your feedback. But, what if I had wanted 'intersection' of results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is always the "raw" and really Mongo syntax available by just pulling from the underlying driver.

A "union" basically means [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```
Event.collection.find({
    "$or" => [
        { "start_time" => { 
            "$gte" => current_date.to_s, 
            "$lte" => date_after_2_weeks.to_s
        },
        { "stop_time" => 
            "$gte" => current_date.to_s,
            "$lte" => date_after_2_weeks.to_s
        }
    ]
})
```

And a "intersection" basically means [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/):

```
Event.collection.find({
    "start_time" => { 
        "$gte" => current_date.to_s, 
        "$lte" => date_after_2_weeks.to_s
    },
    "stop_time" => {
        "$gte" => current_date.to_s,
        "$lte" => date_after_2_weeks.to_s
    }
})
```

Which is implicit as you might gather. So no need for the specific operand. The field names are after all, different.

Maybe there is a "railsy" way to do this, but the specific syntax always works.

Comment: But going through Moped (i.e. `Event.collection`) just gives you a bunch of Hashes so it isn't terribly useful for querying.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. The $or query did the job. And I used it with Event.where() as @kuadrosx suggested.